# Are the $\inf$ and $\lim$ interchangeable in the infinite-horizon discrete-time LQR problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

My question is about the infinite-horizon linear-quadratic regulator (LQR) problem. Consider the following linear and time-invariant system
$$
x_{k+1} = Ax_k + Bu_k
$$
Given the initial state vector $x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$, our objective is to solve the following optimization problem
$$
\inf_{f_0,f_1,\dots} \left[\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x_k^TQx_k + u_k^TRu_k\right] \tag{1}
$$
where $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is the sequence of *policies* such that $u_k = f_k(x_k)$. In the notes and books that I've read, I noticed that the following optimization problem is solved instead:
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \left[\inf_{f_0,\dots,f_{N-1}} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x_k^TQx_k + u_k^TRu_k\right] \tag{2}
$$
where the $\inf$ and $\lim$ are interchanged. More specifically, I've found that authors tend to take the limit of the discrete-time *finite* horizon Riccati difference equation, which suggests that they implicitly performed the interchange shown in $(2)$. However, I'm not sure why this interchange is valid, even when we assume that $(A,B)$ is stabilizable (we assume that $y_k = x_k$ for simplicity, such that $(A,C)$ is observable). That is, why is the solution of the problem in $(1)$ equivalent to the solution of the problem in $(2)$? I'd appreciate any guidance on this.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Hi, I noticed that you've answered several optimal control questions in the past. Would you mind taking a look at this?

Comment: At a first glance both should be the same, since in both cases one eventually evaluates the infimum at $N=\infty$. But which book sources are you using, since their context might be relevant?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I'm referring mainly to proposition 4.1, page 135, chapter 4: "Problems with Perfect State Information", in the 3rd edition of the book "Dynamic Programming and Optimal Control" by Dimitri Bertsekas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following optimal control problem

$$
J_T(x_0)=\min_{u}\sum_{i=0}^{T-1}x_i^TQx_i+u_i^TRu_i
$$
where $x_{k+1}=Ax_k+Bu_k$. From dynamic programming, we have that

$$
J_T(x_0)=x_0^TP_T(0)x_0
$$
where $P_T(k)$ solves the Difference Riccati Equation (DRE)

$$
P_T(k-1)=\mathcal{R}(P_T(k)),\ P_T(T)=0.
$$

In that case, the optimal control law is given by $u_k=K_kx_k$ where $K_k=-(R+B^TP_T(k+1)B)^{-1}B^TP_T(k+1)A$.

---

On the other, we can define the cost

$$
J_\infty(x_0)=\min_{u}\sum_{i=0}^{
\infty}x_i^TQx_i+u_i^TRu_i.
$$

and we know that this cost is equal to

$$
J_\infty(x_0)=x_0^TP_\infty x_0
$$
where $P_\infty$ is the stabilizing solution of the Algebraic Riccati Equation (ARE)

$$
P_\infty=\mathcal{R}(P_\infty).
$$

By stabilizing solution, it is meant here that $A+BK$ is Schur stable where
$K=-(R+B^TP_\infty B)^{-1}B^TP_\infty A$.

---

The following still contains gap and unclear points which I will fix when I understand how to do it correctly. In the meantime that can just serve as an indicative answer. We show that $P_N(0)\to P_\infty$ as $T\to\infty$.

First of all, it is important to note that $P_{T+1}(0)\succeq P_T(0)$ because the integrand is nonnegative. Assumming now that the pair $(A,B)$ is stabilizable, there exists a $K$ such that $A+BK$ is Schur stable.

This means that we have
$$
J_T(x_0)\le\min_{u}\sum_{i=0}^{T-1}x_i^T(Q+K^TRK)x_i=x_0^T\left(\sum_{i=0}^{T-1}((A+BK)^i)^T(Q+K^TRK)A+BK)^i\right)
$$
and we have that the sum is converging as $T\to\infty$ to, say, $Q$. Therefore, this implies that $P_T(0)\preceq Q$. As a result, the sequence $\{P_T(0)\}_T$ is nondcreasing and upper bounded, which means that it is converging to a limit $P$, which is assumed to be positive definite.

Since it is the solution of a sequence, then it must be converging to a stationary solution of the DRE. In fact, since it is positive definite, it is the unique positive definite solution to the ARE and we have that $P=P_\infty$ (this needs to be better supported).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding of the strategy in your answer is to show that $\lim_{T \to \infty} J_T(x_0) = J_\infty (x_0)$ by first showing that $\lim_{T \to \infty} P_T(0) = P_\infty$. This of course assumes that $$\lim_{T \to \infty} P_T(0) = P_\infty \implies \lim_{T \to \infty} J_T(x_0) = J_\infty (x_0)$$ since both $\lim_{T \to \infty} J_T(x_0)$ and $J_\infty (x_0)$ are quadratic forms with respect to $x_0$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. This is correct. The convergence is in the strong topology here. So, that will be true for all intial conditions.