# How can I define uniform convergence for this sequence of functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, uniform-convergence, control-theory, optimal-control

Consider the following recurrence relation
$$
x_{k+1} = Ax_k + Bu_k
$$
where

- $x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$ is the initial condition,
- $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb R^{n \times m}$, and
- $u_k \in \mathbb R^m$ is an external input at the $k$th timestep (can be chosen as desired).

Suppose we then define the following "cost" function
$$
J_{N-1}\left(x_0,u_0,\dots,u_{N-1}\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x_k^T Q x_k + u_k^T R u_k \tag{1}
$$
where $Q \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is positive semi-definite and $R \in \mathbb R^{m \times m}$ is positive definite. Additionally, let $\mathcal U(x_0)$ be the set of infinite sequences of vectors $(u_0,u_1,\dots)$ such that, for the given initial condition $x_0$,

- the chosen sequence $(u_0,u_1,\dots) \in \mathcal U(x_0)$ results in $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_k = 0$, and
- $\exists M \in \mathbb N, k \geq M \implies u_k = 0$.

I want to show that, given the initial condition $x_0$, when $(u_0,u_1,\dots) \in \mathcal U(x_0)$, the objective function in $(1)$ converges **uniformly** to some value $J_\infty(x_0,u_0,u_1,\dots)$ that depends on $x_0$ and $(u_0,u_1,\dots)$.

However, I'm having trouble defining uniform convergence in this case, since each of the functions in the sequence $J_0(x_0,u_0),J_1(x_0,u_0,u_1),J_2(x_0,u_0,u_1,u_2),\dots$ have different domains. Any suggestions on how I can define uniform convergence here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cost should be here a function of $x_0$ only here as the sequence of inputs is chosen a priori. As a result, we define

$$
J_{N-1}(x_0) = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\left(x_k^T Q x_k + u_k^T R u_k\right).
$$

For the sum to converge you need that $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}x_k^T Q x_k$ to converge to a constant, so you need something stronger than just $x_k\to0$. The issue is that the input becomes zero after a certain time, so you will

- either need $\{Q^{1/2}y_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell_2$ where $y_{k+1}=Ay_k$ (which is weaker than asking for $A$ to be Schur stable), or
- need the input to drive the state to a value $x(M)$ for which $Q^{1/2}x(M)=0$ and $Ax(M)=x(M)$. This includes $x(M)=0$ as special case.

With any of those assumptions, you will directly get the pointwise convergence of $J_N(x_0)$ to $J_\infty(x_0)$. The uniform convergence (i.e. for all $x_0$, possibly in some compact set) is more difficult to prove and you will certainly need more assumptions.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The feedback is very helpful. Based on your argument, it seems that proving uniform convergence is difficult. In that case, my question was actually supposed to be a stepping stone to an answer for my main question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4840805/652310). The idea was that I would prove uniform convergence, and then argue that it is possible to interchange the $\inf$ and $\lim$ that is shown in that question. However, it now seems that this argument will not work. Could you possibly have a look at that other question?

Comment: You do not want to necessarily prove uniform convergence here, rather pointwise convergence. Another thing is that above you consider a sequence of inputs whereas in the optimal control problem that sequence is not any sequence that converges to zero, it is a very specific one and this matters. I have seen your other question and I still need to formulate a good answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. I would really appreciate it if you include this as part of your answer to my other question, as that question is really the more important one in this case. I really appreciate your help so far, thank you!